# Losing this while calling map function of array

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
Array.prototype.map.call(arr,this.parse)
```

For the  code above, what I am doing is I apply `this.parse` on array `arr`, where in `this.parse` I use some on the function (e.g, `this.func1`).

Nevertheless, I lost the `this` when calling `this.func1`, it seems that it is points to the global object rather than the current class. What is the correct method of retaining `this`?

**Update**
As suggest by answers below, I use

```
arr.map(this.parse.bind(this))
```

and it works! Thanks!

Comment: How did you define the `parse` function on `this`?  How it was added would affect what `this` points to.

Comment: @pgreen2. It's not how the function defined, it is how it's called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind `this.parse` to the current `this`. Remember that `this` is not lexically scoped, it depends on how the function is called. [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) lets you specify what `this` will be no matter how it's called

```
Array.prototype.map.call(arr, this.parse.bind(this));
```

Another option is the second optional parameter to parse, which lets you specify what `this` will be. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
Array.prototype.map.call(arr, this.parse, this);
```

Yet another option is to use arrow functions which do use a lexically scoped `this`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
Array.prototype.map.call(arr, 
    (current, index, array) => this.parse(current, index, array));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just assuming you're using Typescript since you tagged the post with "typescript". Let's take a look at what you've written:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(arr,this.parse)
```

Why are you using call() in the first place? Is there some reason? What you've written is equivalent to:

```
arr.map(this.parse)
```

From Mozilla's [reference on the Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

> arr.map(callback[, **thisArg**])
>
> **If a thisArg parameter is provided to map, it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value. Otherwise, the value undefined will be passed for use as its this value.** The this value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function.

I think what you're really looking to do is capture the current object's **this** context. Typescript won't do that if you just reference the function's name, because Javascript doesn't do that and Typescript strives to be backwards-compatible with existing Javascript.

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
private parse(str: string): string {
    // Just an example -- parse by converting to uppercase
    return str.toUpperCase();
}

public myMethod(arr: string[]) {
    // Parse all the elements of arr
    let parsedArray = arr.map((elem) => this.parse(elem));

    // ...
}
```